# How to connect sql server through internet?

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

How to connect sql server from client systems to main host system through internet and IP address?, like a software in the company representatives that connected to main office's software through Internet‬?

Comment: What do you mean? Expose SQL server to public Internet? Sounds like a security issue. Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your sql server should be allowing [remote connections](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx). Then you need to get through firewall. This isn't the appropriate/recommended way of accessing data though.

I would recommend that you use services in between to fetch data. so your architecture should be something like this

> Client machine--Web services(any type)--Database
>
> Database--web services--client machine

Answer (score 0):

You should Enable Network Access in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[See](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165718%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

On the Start menu, choose All Programs, point to Microsoft SQL Server and then click SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Optionally, you can open Computer Manager by right-clicking My Computer and choosing Manage. In Computer Management, expand Services and Applications, expand SQL Server Configuration Manager.
  List item

Expand SQL Server Network Configuration, and then click Protocols for InstanceName.
In the list of protocols, right-click the protocol you want to enable, and then click Enable.
The icon for the protocol will change to show that the protocol is enabled.
To disable the protocol, follow the same steps, but choose Disable in step 3.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server hosted in your network ? if so then you will have to configure server to allow access to users

If it is not in your network then you will need to open firewall for client `IP`.